# How to add/use a build tag?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In my build definition I have:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '##vso[build.addbuildtag]pr-completed'
  displayName: 'add pr-completed buildtag'
```

I would expect this to add a `pr-completed` tag to the build. In my release pipeline I have a stage called `stage 1`. In this stage I have set a `artifact filter`:

[image]

But after running a build I get:

[image]

Am I implementing tags wrongly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a mistake in the `build.addbuildtag` script:

```
script: Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]pr-completed"
```

I forgot the `Write-host` part.

Everything works now. Leaving this question as a reference for other people.